# Empty braces around std::make_index_sequence

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14

In [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) example on CppR:

```
template<typename Array, std::size_t... I>
decltype(auto) a2t_impl(const Array& a, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(a[I]...);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
decltype(auto) a2t(const std::array<T, N>& a)
{
    return a2t_impl(a, Indices());
}

template<typename Func, typename Tup, std::size_t... index>
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    return func(std::get<index>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...);
}

template<typename Func, typename Tup>
decltype(auto) invoke(Func&& func, Tup&& tup)
{
    constexpr auto Size = std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tup>::type>::value;
    return invoke_helper(std::forward<Func>(func),
                         std::forward<Tup>(tup),
                         std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}
```

there are these lines, which confuse me a lot:

```
std::make_index_sequence<N>
std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}
```

Why are the curly braces added at the end at times (and omitting them causes a compile error) and why are they sometimes not?

Comment: The curly braces are used to create an object of that type

Comment: Are you sure this is a c++11 code and not c++14? Standard really does make a difference :)

Comment: @W.F. That's definitely C++14. I'm editing the question. Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first instance (`std::make_index_sequence<N>`) is used in a template argument list.  It's only saying that the template type parameter `Indices` defaults to the type `std::make_index_sequence<N>`.  No instances of anything are created there, the use is declarative.

The second instance (`std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}`) is creating a default constructed instance of that type.  The `{}` are the new C++ syntax for initialization.  When the braces are empty the object will be default constructed.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_index_sequence` is ideally defined as:

```
template<std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>;
```

`std::make_integer_sequence` is ideally defined as:

```
template<class T, T N>
using make_integer_sequence = std::integer_sequence<T, /* a sequence 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1 */ >;
```

And `std::integer_sequence` is a type from `utility` header:

```
template< class T, T... Ints >
class integer_sequence;
```

Therefore, you can use it as any other type and invoke its default constructor, that is not strange at all.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for further details.